# Trouble understanding the behavior of `foldr` and `map` in Haskell

Tags: haskell, ghci

I have a function `prefixes` that, given `[1, 2, 3]`, returns the prefixes `[[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]`. It is defined as follows:

```
prefixes :: Num a => [a] -> [[a]]
prefixes = foldr (\x acc -> [x] : (map ((:) x) acc)) []
```

I have spent nearly two days trying to understand why this works. When I debug this in my head, I imagine this for `prefixes [1, 2, 3]`:

```
foldr call|__________________________________________________________________________
    1     | [1] : (map ((:) 1) [])
          |
          |         where x = 1 and acc = []
          |         returns acc = [[1]]
          |
    2     | [2] : (map ((:) 2) [[1]])
          |
          |         where x = 2 and acc = [[1]]
          |         and (map ((:) 2) [[1]])
          |                  returns acc = [[1, 2]]
          |         and [2] : [[1, 2]]
          |                  returns [[2], [1, 2]]
          |
    3     | [3] : (map ((:) 3) [[2], [1, 2]])
          |
          |         where x = 3 and acc = [[2], [1, 2]]
          |         and (map ((:) 3) [[2], [1, 2]])
          |                  returns acc = [[2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
          |         and [3] : [[2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
          |                  returns [[3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
          |
```

And then the function terminates and returns `[[3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]`. But obviously that is not happening. It returns `[[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]`.

In Ghci, I find this:

```
Stopped in Main.prefixes, ex.hs:21:20-63

_result :: [a] -> [[a]] = _
[ex.hs:21:20-63] *Main> :step

Stopped in Main.prefixes, ex.hs:21:37-59

_result :: [[Integer]] = _
acc :: [[Integer]] = _
x :: Integer = 1

[ex.hs:21:37-59] *Main> :step

[[1]

Stopped in Main.prefixes, ex.hs:21:44-58

_result :: [[Integer]] = _
acc :: [[Integer]] = _
x :: Integer = 1

[ex.hs:21:44-58] *Main> :step
Stopped in Main.prefixes, ex.hs:21:37-59

_result :: [[Integer]] = _
acc :: [[Integer]] = _
x :: Integer = 2

[ex.hs:21:37-59] *Main> :step
,
Stopped in Main.prefixes, ex.hs:21:49-53

_result :: [Integer] -> [Integer] = _
x :: Integer = 1

[ex.hs:21:49-53] *Main> :step
[1,2]
Stopped in Main.prefixes, ex.hs:21:44-58

_result :: [[Integer]] = _
acc :: [[Integer]] = _
x :: Integer = 2

[ex.hs:21:44-58] *Main> :step
Stopped in Main.prefixes, ex.hs:21:37-59

_result :: [[Integer]] = _
acc :: [[Integer]] = _
x :: Integer = 3

[ex.hs:21:37-59] *Main> :step
,
[1Stopped in Main.prefixes, ex.hs:21:49-53

_result :: [Integer] -> [Integer] = _
x :: Integer = 2

[ex.hs:21:49-53] *Main> :step
,2,3]
Stopped in Main.prefixes, ex.hs:21:44-58

_result :: [[Integer]] = _
acc :: [[Integer]] = _
x :: Integer = 3

[ex.hs:21:44-58] *Main> :step

]
```

Which I interpret as:

```
__lines___|__________________________________________________________________________
 21:37-59 | [1] : (map ((:) 1) acc)           ->  [[1]
          |        
          |              
          |
 21:44-58 |       (map ((:) 1) acc)           ->  does nothing, as acc = []
          |                                                 
          |              
          |
 21:37-59 | [2] : (map ((:) 2) acc)           ->  ,
          |         
          |              
          |
 21:49-53 |            ((:) 1)                ->  [1, 2]
          |            
          |                 
          |
 21:44-58 |       (map ((:) 2) acc)           ->  outputs nothing
          |         
          |              
          |
 21:37-59 | [3] : (map ((:) 3) acc)           ->  ,[1
          |         
          |              
          |
 21:49-53 |            ((:) 2)                ->  , 2, 3]
          |             
          |
 21:44-58 |       (map ((:) 3) acc)           ->  ]
          |
```

Printing `[[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]`. Could someone explain why, when lines 49-53 are evaluated, `x` is the x value from the previous `foldr` invocation?

I know that `(map ((:) x) acc)` can be expanded to `(foldr ((:) . ((:) x)) [] acc)`, as `map f = foldr ((:) . f) []`. So I rewrote the function into the following

```
prefixesSolution :: Num a => [a] -> [[a]]
prefixesSolution = foldr (\x acc -> [x] : (foldr ((:) . ((:) x)) [] acc)) []
```

And this works as well. Now, the lambda passed to the second `foldr` `((:) . ((:) x))` I would imagine could be refactored as `(\ element accumulator -> (element:accumulator) . ((element:accumulator) x))`. But this does not work: `Couldn't match expected type ‘a -> a0 -> b0’ with actual type ‘[[a]]’`. All this I have done in order to pinpoint exactly what is happening.

I also do not understand the function passed to map `((:) x)`.

I apologize for how convoluted this post is. At this point I don't even know what I don't know. If someone could clearly walk me through this function I would be so so grateful.

Comment: `(:) 2` is a function that _prepends_ `2` to the input list -- I think you are assuming it appends instead. It is equivalent to `\xs -> 2:xs`.

Comment: And the second piece of the puzzle is that `foldr` works right to left, not left to right. That's what `r` in its name stands for.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin Then why, when I invoke the debugger, does x start at 1 and work up to 3?

Comment: I don't have the time for a long answer right now (sorry), but the short answer is that the debugger doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Maybe like this: the actual execution of the program does not always match the order in which functions are applied to parameters.

Comment: @chi so why can I not refactor `foldr ((:) . ((:) x)) [] acc` into `foldr (\ element accumulator -> (element:accumulator) . (x:accumulator)) [] acc`?

Comment: Or maybe like this: in Haskell functions are applied to parameters before evaluating those parameters' values, not after.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin That actually helps a lot, now as I debug it in my head, I can see clearly why the result is `[[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]`

Comment: Compare `foldr f z (x:xs) = f x (foldr f z xs)` and `foldl f z (x:xs) = foldl f (f z x) xs`. Both start with `x`, but differ in the order in which `f` and the recursive call on `xs` are used. `foldr` lets `f` decide when (and if) `foldr` is applied, while `foldl` decides when (and if) `f` is evaluated. (Strict versions of `foldl` force `f z x` immediately to avoid thunk buildup, but neither kind of left fold can handle infinite lists.)

Comment: `(:) . ((:) x)` composes two functions, while `(element:accumulator) . (x:accumulator)` tries to compose two lists which is a type error. The first function composition can also be written as `\xs -> (:) (x:xs)` which eta-expands to `\xs ys -> (x:xs):ys`.

Answer (score 5):

`foldr` accumulates from the end of the list.

Initially `acc = []` (using the second argument of `foldr`).

Starting from the end, we apply the given function `\x acc -> [x] : (map ((:) x) acc)` with `x = 3`:

```
[3] : map (3 :) []
= [[3]]
```

With `acc = [[3]]`, add the preceding element, `x = 2`:

```
[2] : map (2 :) [[3]]
= [[2], [2,3]]
```

With `acc = [[2], [2,3]]`, add the preceding element, `x = 1`:

```
[1] : map (1 :) [[2], [2,3]]
= [[1], [1,2], [1,2,3]]
```

You can also still evaluate `foldr` "left to right", but in that case, remember that `acc` gets instantiated with "the next recursive call".

```
foldr f b (x : xs) = f x (foldr f b xs)

prefixes [1,2,3]
= [1] : map (1 :) (prefixes [2,3])    -- acc = prefixes [2,3], the next recursive call
= [1] : map (1 :) ([2] : map (2 :) (prefixes [3]))
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting with the question about the function passed to map:

In Haskell, all operators are also functions. By itself, `:` is the list construction ("cons") operator:

```
 1 : [2,3]  -- > [1,2,3]
```

If you put parentheses around it, it becomes a prefix function instead of an infix operator:

```
 (:) 1 [2,3]  -- > [1,2,3]
```

When you remember that Haskell function application is curried, then you can see that `(:) 1` is necessarily a function that prepends 1 to a list:

```
 f = (:) 1
 f [2,3]   -- > [1,2,3]
```

So the function passed to `map` is one that takes a list as its argument and prepends `x` (the current item from the `foldr`) to that list.

The surrounding function prepends `[x]` to the result of that `map`, growing the list.

Next let's talk about `foldr` itself. It may help to think of the list [1,2,3] as the sequence of cons calls required to create it. In tree form that looks like this:

```
   (:)
1      (:)
    2      (:)
        3      []
```

And in Haskell you could write it like this:

```
(:) 1 ( (:) 2 ( (:) 3 [] ) )
```

Given the above, what the call `foldr func init [1,2,3]` does is replace the final `[]` with the `init` value and all the `(:)`s with the supplied `func`. So the final result is the same as the result of this expression, which you can think of as an expansion of the `foldr` version:

```
func 1 ( func 2 ( func 3 init ) )
```

That is, `foldr` first calls the func on 3 (which becomes `x`) and `[]` (which becomes `acc`). (Technically, it calls the function on 3, and the result of that call is another function that it then calls on `[]`, but that's just how function application works in Haskell; the difference is not important to this particular discussion.) Then it calls the func on 2 and the result of the first call, and then it calls it on 1 and the result of the second call.

As we established above, the func first does a  `map ((:) 3) []` - returning `[]`, since mapping anything across the empty list just returns the empty list - and prepends `[3]` to the result, giving `[[3]]`.

Then it calls the func on 2 and `[[3]]`. The map returns `[[2,3]]`, to which it prepends `[2]`, yielding `[[2],[2,3]]`.

Finally it calls the func on 1 and `[[2],[2,3]]`. The map returns `[[1,2],[1,2,3]]` and the func prepends `[1]` to it, yielding the final answer `[[1],[1,2],[1,2,3]]`.

Answer (score 1):

When evaluating something like `prefixes [1,2,3]` by hand, you should try to be very careful in writing out each step of the evaluation.

I would look at it like this:

Before we start, I suggest a couple of steps of preparation. I'll also give variables fresh names as we go, to hopefully make things more clear.

It will help to write the pattern matches as `case` expressions, so we will do this next.

We can observe that `foldr` can be written as

```
foldr f z list =
  case list of
    [] -> z
    (y:ys) -> f y (foldr f z ys)
```

I'll skip over some of the details of specific `map` applications later on and focus more on the `foldr` steps. If this is unclear, I can expand on that more.

Now that we've got that taken care of, we can evaluate. I'm not going to focus so much on the evaluation order, since this will not affect the final result. This will let me simplify a couple of things. As a result, you shouldn't necessarily assume this is *exactly* what the computer is doing (even though the result is the same here, it could have differences in terms of memory efficiency, time efficiency and possibly strictness properties).

```
    prefixes [1,2,3]

==> {definition of prefixes}
    foldr (\x acc -> [x] : (map ((:) x) acc)) [] [1,2,3]

==> {definition of foldr}
    let f = \x acc -> [x] : (map ((:) x) acc)
    in
    case [1,2,3] of
      [] -> []
      (y:ys) -> f y (foldr f [] ys)

==> {reduce case match on known value}
    let f = \x acc -> [x] : (map ((:) x) acc)
    in
    f 1 (foldr f [] [2,3])

==> {definition of foldr}
    let f = \x acc -> [x] : (map ((:) x) acc)
    in
    f 1 (case [2,3] of
           [] -> []
           (y:ys) -> f y (foldr f [] ys))

==> {reduce case match on known value}
    let f = \x acc -> [x] : (map ((:) x) acc)
    in
    f 1 (f 2 (foldr f [] [3]))

==> {definition of foldr}
    let f = \x acc -> [x] : (map ((:) x) acc)
    in
    f 1 (f 2 (case [3] of
               [] -> []
               (y:ys) -> f y (foldr f [] ys)))

==> {reduce case match on known value}
    let f = \x acc -> [x] : (map ((:) x) acc)
    in
    f 1 (f 2 (f 3 (foldr f [] [])))

==> {definition of foldr}
    let f = \x acc -> [x] : (map ((:) x) acc)
    in
    f 1 (f 2 (f 3 (case [] of
                    [] -> []
                    (y:ys) -> f y (foldr f [] ys))))

==> {reduce case match on known value}
    let f = \x acc -> [x] : (map ((:) x) acc)
    in
    f 1 (f 2 (f 3 []))

==> {apply f}
    let f = \x acc -> [x] : (map ((:) x) acc)
    in
    f 1 (f 2 ([3] : map ((:) 3) []))

==> {apply map}
    let f = \x acc -> [x] : (map ((:) x) acc)
    in
    f 1 (f 2 ([3] : []))

==> {list sugar}
    let f = \x acc -> [x] : (map ((:) x) acc)
    in
    f 1 (f 2 [[3]])

==> {apply f}
    let f = \x acc -> [x] : (map ((:) x) acc)
    in
    f 1 ([2] : map ((:) 2) [[3]])

==> {apply map}
    let f = \x acc -> [x] : (map ((:) x) acc)
    in
    f 1 ([2] : [((:) 2) [3]])

==> {list sugar}
    let f = \x acc -> [x] : (map ((:) x) acc)
    in
    f 1 [[2], [2,3]]

==> {apply f}
    [1] : map ((:) 1) [[2], [2,3]]

==> {apply map}
    [1] : [((:) 1) [2], ((:) 1) [2,3]]

==> {list sugar}
    [1] : [[1,2], [1,2,3]]

==> {list sugar}
    [[1], [1,2], [1,2,3]]
```

This is the general process can be used to understand the result obtained from evaluating expressions. Note that every step is a valid Haskell expression that behaves identically to the original expression. Essentially, I just expanded definitions, reduced `case` expressions when the `case` is matching on a `(:) ... ...` or a `[]`, applied functions (using beta-reduction) and introduced some syntactic sugar for lists to make things a bit easier to read in parts. Those kinds of steps already cover a significant portion of the tools you need to reduce most Haskell expressions by hand.

A very similar process can also be used for [equational reasoning](https://www.haskellforall.com/2013/12/equational-reasoning.html), which can be used as a systematic technique to optimize Haskell programs. It works by replacing expressions with other expressions that always give the same result but could have different efficiency characteristics. Essentially anything [written by Richard Bird](http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/people/publications/date/Richard.Bird.html) will provide examples of equational reasoning, among others.